# PHP: any shortcut for str_starts_with and str_ends_with with haystack and needle also interverted?

Tags: php, regex

I need the following condition:

```
if (
  str_starts_with($foo, $bar) ||
  str_starts_with($bar, $foo) ||
  str_ends_with($foo, $bar) ||
  str_ends_with($bar, $foo)
) {
  ...
}
```

But it looks a bit eloquent, is there a shorter way to write it? Maybe with regex?

Comment: Define your own function.

Comment: A regex if you get verbose., even abstract verbose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use [preg-match](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) function

```
if (preg_match("/^{$foo}.*|.*{$foo}$/", $bar)
   || preg_match("/^{$bar}.*|.*{$bar}$/", $foo) ) {
    echo "A match was found...";
}
```